# Passing a number to a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to pass a number to a React component but it is getting parsed as string ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/utj7qprh/2/)). How do I make React understand that I am passing a number? Should I cast the string to a number in the component?

```js
var Rectangle = React.createClass({
   
    render: function() {

        return <div>
            <div>{this.props.intValue + 10}</div>
            <div>{this.props.stringValue + 10}</div>
        </div>;
    }
});
 
React.render(<Rectangle intValue="10" stringValue="Hello" />
    , document.getElementById('container'));
```

```html
<script src="https://facebook.github.io/react/js/jsfiddle-integration.js"></script>

<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 87, accepted):

It seems that in case of integers (and actually for strings as well) I should be passing the numbers via `{}` like so:

`React.render(<Rectangle intValue={10} stringValue={"Hello"} />, document.getElementById('container'));`

Comment: Why would you have to pass a string like ```stringValue={"Hello"}``` instead of ```stringValue="Hello"```?

Comment: You can do it either way with strings but for consistency sake you might do both the same way

Answer (score 15):

You can either use:

```
<MyComponent param1={10} param2={20} />
```

Or:

```
<MyComponent {...{param1: 10, param2: 20}} />
```