# onchange on different select element different result

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, typescript, types

i'm new on react/typescript world here i have two Select elements one is normal and another is antd version, for some reason on antd version onchange wont give any error but on normal version i get this error:

```
(JSX attribute) React.SelectHTMLAttributes<HTMLSelectElement>.onChange?: React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLSelectElement> | undefined
Type '(customerId: string) => void' is not assignable to type 'ChangeEventHandler<HTMLSelectElement>'.
  Types of parameters 'customerId' and 'event' are incompatible.
    Type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(2274, 9): The expected type comes from property 'onChange' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<SelectHTMLAttributes<HTMLSelectElement>, HTMLSelectElement>'
```

my code is this :

```html
  <Select id="senderId" onChange={setSender}>
        {customerList.map((item, idx) => (
          <option key={idx} value={item.id}>
            {item.name}
          </option>
        ))}
      </Select>
```

just change first letter of Select to lower case you will get normal select

Comment: Hey hello, apparently there is an issue with the function that you have in onChange. Can you share a little example of your components in codesandbox.io or something similar?

Comment: as i said it is working with antd, but i want to use normal select, why should give error ?

Comment: Because antd could manage in a different way the onChange event. You need to handle the onChange event with an event parameter. setSender = (event) => {event.target.value}

Comment: https://codepen.io/Cuchu/pen/xxgxZmo?editors=001 this is from antd. They are using a key in the method onChange. You need to use a different function in your select. And catch the event instead of key.

Answer (score 0):

In your select, you need to use a different function, because antd receive a key in the onChange event. https://codepen.io/Cuchu/pen/xxgxZmo?editors=001

The select component onChange event uses an event as a parameter.

```
setSender = (event) => {
    customerId = event.target.value;
    /* continue */
}
```

Check the console here: https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-breeze-4jlc7?file=/src/App.js

```
const setSender = (event) => { 
    /* I am not sure about this in typescript */
    if(event instanceof String) {
       customerId = event;
    } else {
       customerId = event.target.value;
    }
    /* customerId = event.target.value; */

    if (customerId === null || customerId === "") {
       setSelectedCustomerId(""); 
    } else {
       setSelectedCustomerId(customerId); 
    }
};
```

Your function ^^^

But don't copy and paste, check and analyze the different.
onChange with antd receives a string (key selected).
onChange with select receives an event.

Last comment, I think that you need to use {}

```
<select id="senderId" size={4} onChange={setSender}>
```

Comment: if its not too much, that my select has also 'size' attribute, which works but still gives this : (JSX attribute) React.SelectHTMLAttributes<HTMLSelectElement>.size?: number | undefined
Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number | undefined'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(2272, 9): The expected type comes from property 'size' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<SelectHTMLAttributes<HTMLSelectElement>, HTMLSelectElement>'

Comment: Change the name of the function for select tag, because it will fail for and. Or you can check the type of the parameter and use directly customerId or event.

Comment: could you add that to your answer

Comment: Yes, that error is because you are using a string and the size parameter only accepts number or undefined. Check how you are passing that property.

Comment: like this :       <select id="senderId" size="4" onChange={setSender}>

Comment: Try with {4} - https://stackoverflow.com/a/29474674/2209876

Comment: Today I saw some questions about ant design react, is it a good library? I have been working with React for one month and at the moment, I didn't use any library for the UI. Anyway, if this answer helpt you, please mark it as the solution to close the question.